# Primary Key in Access for multi Client_ID

Tags: ms-access-2016

I am uploading legacy data to MS-Access via Excel. We have client Medications data and demographics etc. The common key is really the Client_ID. However in all data sets there will be multi rows per client, if there are more than one medication etc. it's a new row.
My concern is should my Primary Key be the Client_ID or should MS-Access auto create it, or should it be a combo of these?

Comment: What you need to do is *normalize.*  That means you will have a Clients table with Client ID as the primary key.  Each client will exist in the Clients table only once.  All of your related tables will have Client ID as a *foreign key* in a one-to-many relationship with the corresponding client in the Clients table.  I strongly suggest you enlist the help of someone who is familiar with this database design process, as getting it wrong will cause you no end of grief later on.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Thank you, I follow your advice later tonight. In meantime, I can create the master client table with the client_ID.